# In app purchase within SKScene using SpriteNode?

Tags: swift, xcode6, sprite-kit, in-app-purchase, skscene

I'm using this code to unlock a scene once a purchase has been made. My first question is whether the code is correct in that the purchase will work. My second question is that I'm asking the purchase to happen when a sprite node is pressed, am I calling the correct function to happen in touches began? All of the code below is within an SKScene

```
    var list = [SKProduct]()
    var p = SKProduct()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        println("IAP is enabled, loading")
        var productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects: "_Scene1_Unlock")
        var request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start() } else {
        println("please enable IAPS") }
}


    func addScene1() {
        println("scene1 added") }

    func RestorePurchases() {
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions() }

    func btnAddScene1() {
        for product in list {
            var prodID = product.productIdentifier
            if(prodID == "_Scene1_Unlock") {
                p = product
                buyProduct()
                break; } } }

    func buyProduct() {
        println("buy" + p.productIdentifier)
        var pay = SKPayment(product: p)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment) }

    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
        println("product request")
        var myProduct = response.products
        for product in myProduct {
            println("product added")
            println(product.productIdentifier)
            println(product.localizedTitle)
            println(product.localizedDescription)
            println(product.price)
            list.append(product as! SKProduct) } }

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
        println("transactions restored")
        var purchasedItemIDS = []
        for transaction in queue.transactions {
            var t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String
            switch prodID {
            case "_Scene1_Unlock":
                println("remove ads")
                addScene1()
            default:
                println("IAP not setup")}}}

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
        println("add paymnet")
        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        var trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
        println(trans.error)
        switch trans.transactionState {
        case .Purchased:
        println("buy, ok unlock iap here")
        println(p.productIdentifier)
        let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String
        switch prodID {
        case "_Scene1_Unlock":
        println("remove ads")
        addScene1()
        default:
        println("IAP not setup") }
        queue.finishTransaction(trans)
        break;
        case .Failed:
        println("buy error")
        queue.finishTransaction(trans)
        break;
        default:
        println("default")
        break; }}}

    func finishTransaction(trans:SKPaymentTransaction) {
        println("finish trans") }

    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, removedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
        println("remove trans") }


    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.stopScene1 {
            btnAddScene1()
            }
```

Comment: From what I can see, it looks pretty good. I answered a question exactly like this yesterday if you would like to take a look, here is the link. [in app purchase link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907050/in-app-purchase-in-skscene)