# in app purchase in SKScene

Tags: swift, xcode6, sprite-kit, in-app-purchase, skscene

Is it possible to implement an in-app purchase within the `SKScene`? If so, how? I'm trying to use a `SKSpriteNode` as a 'buy' button with no luck. I'm not sure whether the code needs to go in the `SKScene` or the view controller. I've looked at loads of tutorials, but they all seem to be aimed at single view applications rather than in SpriteKit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, put this in your game scene line and make sure you have the framework 'StoreKit' imported

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate {
```

Next, your going to want to put these lines in your didmovetoview. Keep in mind that after the "objects:" The string you put should be the in app purchase identifier you set up using iTunes connect.

```
// Set IAPS
    if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        println("IAP is enabled, loading")
        var productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects: "Put IAP id here")
        var request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        println("please enable IAPS")
    }
```

Outside of any other functions, but still within the game scene, insert these functions and variables

```
//In App Purchases
var list = [SKProduct]()
var p = SKProduct()

func buyProduct() {
    println("buy " + p.productIdentifier)
    var pay = SKPayment(product: p)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)
}

func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
    println("product request")
    var myProduct = response.products

    for product in myProduct {
        println("product added")
        println(product.productIdentifier)
        println(product.localizedTitle)
        println(product.localizedDescription)
        println(product.price)

        list.append(product as! SKProduct)
    }
}

func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
    println("transactions restored")

    var purchasedItemIDS = []
    for transaction in queue.transactions {
        var t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction

        let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

        switch prodID {
        case "IAP id here":

            //Right here is where you should put the function that you want to execute when your in app purchase is complete
        default:
            println("IAP not setup")
        }

    }

    var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Thank You", message: "Your purchase(s) were restored. You may have to restart the app before banner ads are removed.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    alert.show()
}


func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    println("add paymnet")

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        var trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
        println(trans.error)

        switch trans.transactionState {

        case .Purchased, .Restored:
            println("buy, ok unlock iap here")
            println(p.productIdentifier)

            let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String
            switch prodID {
            case "IAP id here":

                //Here you should put the function you want to execute when the purchase is complete
                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Thank You", message: "You may have to restart the app before the banner ads are removed.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()
            default:
                println("IAP not setup")
            }

            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        case .Failed:
            println("buy error")
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        default:
            println("default")
            break;

        }
    }
}

func finishTransaction(trans:SKPaymentTransaction)
{
    println("finish trans")
}
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, removedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)
{
    println("remove trans");
}
```

Next you must name the node you need to do the iAP

```
whateverYourNodeIs.name = "inAppPurchaseNode"
```

Finally, do this in the touchesBegan

```
  let touch =  touches.first as? UITouch
  let positionInScene = touch!.locationInNode(self)
  let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)

if let name = touchedNode.name {
        if name == "inAppPurchaseNode" {

                for product in list {
                    var prodID = product.productIdentifier
                    if(prodID == "iAp id here") {
                        p = product
                        buyProduct()  //This is one of the functions we added earlier
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

    }
```

You will also want this in your touches began to restore the purchases using a different node.

```
    if let name = touchedNode.name {
        if name == "restore" {

             SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
             }
        }
```

Comment: Wherever I put the string "iAP id here" I mean that you must use the in app purchase id you made in iTunes connect

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help, I've looked everywhere for an answer like this!! :) :)

Comment: You are very welcome. Also, I noticed I left some UIAlertViews in the code from a game I made a while ago. You can delete those or just change the text if you want.