# In app purchase in SKScene not working?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, in-app-purchase, skscene

I'm creating a SpriteKit game in Swift and I'm trying to implement in app purchases.

I followed this question here: [in app purchase in SKScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907050/in-app-purchase-in-skscene)

And here is my code:

In didMoveToView:

```
 // Set IAPS
        if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
            println("IAP is enabled, loading")
            var productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects: "GameOverSaveSavior")
            var request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        } else {
            println("please enable IAPS")
        }
```

Outside of didMoveToView but in `GameScene`:

```
 //IN APP PURCHASE ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

    var productList = [SKProduct]()
    var p = SKProduct()

    func purchaseMade() {
        println("they bought it!")
    }

    func buyProduct() {
        println("buy" + p.productIdentifier)

        var pay = SKPayment(product: p)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)
    }
    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
        println("product request")
        var myProduct = response.products

        for product in myProduct {
            println("product added")
            println(product.productIdentifier)
            println(product.localizedTitle)
            println(product.localizedDescription)
            println(product.price)

            productList.append(product as! SKProduct)
        }
    }

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
        println("transactions restored")

        var purchasedItemIDS = []
        for transaction in queue.transactions {
            var t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction

            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

            switch prodID {
            case "GameOverSaveSavior":

                purchaseMade()

                //Right here is where you should put the function that you want to execute when your in app purchase is complete
            default:
                println("IAP not setup")
            }

        }

        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Thank You", message: "Your purchase(s) were restored. You may have to restart the app before banner ads are removed.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()
    }


    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
        println("add paymnet")

        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            var trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
            println(trans.error)

            switch trans.transactionState {

            case .Purchased, .Restored:
                println("buy, ok unlock iap here")
                println(p.productIdentifier)

                let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String
                switch prodID {
                case "GameOverSaveSavior":

                    //Here you should put the function you want to execute when the purchase is complete
                    var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Thank You", message: "You may have to restart the app before the banner ads are removed.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                    alert.show()
                default:
                    println("IAP not setup")
                }

                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break;
            case .Failed:
                println("buy error")
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break;
            default:
                println("default")
                break;

            }
        }
    }

    func finishTransaction(trans:SKPaymentTransaction)
    {
        println("finish trans")
    }
    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, removedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)
    {
        println("remove trans");
    }

 //+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

In touchesBegan for when the in app purchase node is touched:

```
//In app purchase
            if touchedNode == saveMeBtn {

                println("button touched!")
                for product in productList {
                    var prodID = product.productIdentifier
                    if(prodID == "GameOverSaveSavior") {
                        p = product
                        buyProduct()  //This is one of the functions we added earlier
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

All of my code is straight from the question above, and the code compiles without any errors and

> IAP is enabled, loading

and

> product request

is printed to the console at the start of the game.

When the in app purchase button is touched,

> button touched!

is printed to the console but nothing else happens. It doesn't ask the user to purchase anything.

I made sure that the bundle ID in Xcode is the same as in iTunes Connect and that the in app purchase ID is the same. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a good few weeks of work, I found out that you must have your **Paid Applications** agreement filled out completely and accepted in order for your code and products to work. Approval can take  a few days, then you're in the clear.