# Swift, spritekit: In app purchase, product not added?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, in-app-purchase

I'm working in Swift and trying to implement in app purchases in my SKScene. Having some difficulty.

I have followed several tutorials and I believe my code is correct (I can provide full code if you need it) because it compiles without any errors and I copied it, verbatim, from this question that was marked successful: [in app purchase in SKScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907050/in-app-purchase-in-skscene/31910934#31910934)

The problem is that it doesn't work- it doesn't ask the user to purchase the in app purchase or anything, for that matter. I believe the problem is that I am not retrieving the in app purchase from iTunes Connect.

This is what I've done:

1. Gone in Itunes Connect and created an in app purchase under my app's record. My in app purchase's product Id is `"GameOverSaveSavior"`
2. In Xcode, I've turned my app's In app purchase capability to ON, made sure my team is set to my account, AND made sure my Bundle Identifier under info is set to my app's bundle identifier in ITunes Connect

In my code, again I've copied verbatim from the question above and I've substituted my in app purchase's product ID for the one they had. I believe the issue is in this `func`:

```
 func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
        println("product request")
        var myProduct = response.products

        for product in myProduct {
            println("product added")
            println(product.productIdentifier)
            println(product.localizedTitle)
            println(product.localizedDescription)
            println(product.price)

            list.append(product as! SKProduct)
        }
    }
```

When run, "product request" is printed to the console but "product added" is not. What am I doing wrong? Why is it unable to get the product from iTunes Connect?

The only other thing I can think of is that I changed the name of my app within Xcode a while back to match the name in my app record in iTunes Connect. Would that cause this problem?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32419049/swift-spritekit-in-app-purchase-code-runs-nothing-happens and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32303801/in-app-purchase-in-skscene-not-working your other two questions?

Comment: Not really being that I've more figured out the issue now. Thanks

Comment: I would recommend removing those questions then otherwise it makes it look like you are asking the same question over and over. Also I would hate for someone to waste time trying to answer something you already have an answer for :)

Comment: I still don't have an answer! That's my problem. If anyone answered any one of my questions we'd be making progress