# Swift, spritekit: In app purchase code runs, NOTHING happens?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, in-app-purchase

Ok, so I'm working in Swift and I just need help. I have followed 4 different tutorials on how to implement in app purchases in sprite kit with Swift, copied code verbatim, and nothing is working for me.

Here are the steps I have taken:

1. Gone in Itunes Connect and created an in app purchase under my app's record. My in app purchase's product Id is `"GameOverSaveSavior"`
2. In Xcode, I've turned my app's In app purchase capability to `ON`, made sure my team is set to my account, and made sure my Bundle Identifier under info is set to my app's bundle identifier in ITunes Connect
3. Before writing any code, I have `import StoreKit` in my GameScene.swift file

As for code, this is what I have done:

(1) In Gamescene.swift, at the end of my `didMoveToView` func, I have:

```
// Set IAPS
        if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
            println("IAP is enabled, loading")
            var productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects: "GameOverSaveSavior")
            var request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as Set<NSObject>)
            request.delegate = self
            request.start()
        } else {
            println("please enable IAPS")
        }
```

This outputs `"IAP is enabled, loading"` when the app is run.

(2) In GameScene.swift, within the class but outside of `didMoveToView`, I have all the functions and variables others have used for in app purchases:

```
var list = [SKProduct]()
var p = SKProduct()

    func purchaseMade() {
        println("they bought it!")
    }

    func buyProduct() {
        println("buy" + p.productIdentifier)

        var pay = SKPayment(product: p)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)
    }
    func productsRequest(request: SKProductsRequest!, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse!) {
        println("product request")
        var myProduct = response.products

        for product in myProduct {
            println("product added")
            println(product.productIdentifier)
            println(product.localizedTitle)
            println(product.localizedDescription)
            println(product.price)

            list.append(product as! SKProduct)
        }
    }

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
        println("transactions restored")

        var purchasedItemIDS = []
        for transaction in queue.transactions {
            var t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction

            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

            switch prodID {
            case "GameOverSaveSavior":

                purchaseMade()

                //Right here is where you should put the function that you want to execute when your in app purchase is complete
            default:
                println("IAP not setup")
            }

        }

        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Thank You", message: "Your purchase(s) were restored. You may have to restart the app before banner ads are removed.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
        alert.show()
    }


    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
        println("add paymnet")

        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            var trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
            println(trans.error)

            switch trans.transactionState {

            case .Purchased, .Restored:
                println("buy, ok unlock iap here")
                println(p.productIdentifier)

                let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String
                switch prodID {
                case "GameOverSaveSavior":

                    //Here you should put the function you want to execute when the purchase is complete
                    var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Thank You", message: "You may have to restart the app before the banner ads are removed.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                    alert.show()
                default:
                    println("IAP not setup")
                }

                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break;
            case .Failed:
                println("buy error")
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break;
            default:
                println("default")
                break;

            }
        }
    }

    func finishTransaction(trans:SKPaymentTransaction)
    {
        println("finish trans")
    }
    func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, removedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)
    {
        println("remove trans");
    }
```

This outputs `"product request"` to the console when the app is run.

(3) In GameScene.swift, in my `touchesBegan` func, I have the following for when the right button is touched:

```
//In app purchase
            if touchedNode == saveMeBtn {

                println("button touched!")
                for product in list {
                    var prodID = product.productIdentifier
                    if(prodID == "GameOverSaveSavior") {
                        p = product
                        buyProduct()  //This is one of the functions we added earlier
                        break;
                    }
                }
```

This outputs `"button touched!"` when the button is touched.

I do not know what I am doing wrong. The code compiles with no errors, yet nothing occurs when my button is touched. There is no alert asking the user to sign in or to purchase anything- nothing. 
I have mainly followed this question: 
[in app purchase in SKScene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907050/in-app-purchase-in-skscene/31910934#31910934)

Is there anything else I should have done prior to writing the code? Am I missing something in my code?

Comment: @Aidan Kaiser You seem very knowledgeable on the topic of IAPs and I have tried to follow your other answers. Do you have an idea of what I am doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: What about "product added" do you see that log line? are you sure you are getting products from the store?

Comment: @giorashc No, "product added" is not printed to the console so I must not be getting the products from the store. How can I fix that? Is it an iTunes connect problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the product id of the iAP and not its reference name?

Comment: The product ID and reference name are the same, but so yes I'm using the product ID

Comment: what about your app's bundle identifier. is it the same is in itunes for this app?

Comment: I copy and pasted the bundle ID from iTunes connect to where it says bundle identifier in my app's info.plist

Comment: Thats really strange. You can check the invalidProductIdentifiers
 property as it tells you which products were NOT identified by app store. If so it is something with how you defined the iAP

Comment: Alright, thank you. If it is how I defined the iAP (meaning it's a code problem), do you happen know where to find the correct code for swift? Or how to correctly define the iAP?

Comment: Oh I meant in iTunes connect . Your code seems to be fine.

Comment: Got it. So you mean I created the iAP wrong? As in I named it incorrectly or something?

Answer (score 0):

I think I can help you:

I had your issue in the past. And another similar one which I fixed here: [My IAP isn't working. Bugs at func Paymentqueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741619/my-iap-isnt-working-bugs-at-func-paymentqueue)

Here is the solution I had found:

Delete

```
SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
```

everywhere you have it and put it once (ONLY ONCE) in a place where it will be executed each time your app boots up ( I put it in viewDidLoad()).

This will check for all unfinished transactions and terminate them once the app has loaded, thus removing any possible errors before your users triggers an IAP.

P.S.: Also, this wasn't my issue, but make sure to finishTransaction() for each PurchaseState, like here:

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        print("Add Payment")

        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions{
            let trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
            print(trans.error)
            switch trans.transactionState{
            case .Purchased:
                print("IAP unlocked")
                print(p.productIdentifier)

                let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String
                switch prodID{
                case "IAP id":
                    print("Keep on")
                    keepOn()
                default:
                    print("IAP not setup")
                }
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break
            case .Failed:
                print ("Buy error")
                queue.finishTransaction(trans)
                break
            default:
                print("default: Error")
                break
            }
        }
    }
```

Never forget this:

```
 queue.finishTransaction(trans)
```

And make separate case for .Restored.