# Type GameScene does not conform to protocol "SKPaymentTransactionObserver"

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, in-app-purchase

I have an in-app purchase to remove ads and I only have this one error preventing me from compiling my code. Im sure I have the necessary code, but I'm thinking something is missing. Can anyone help?

Here is my code:

```
    import SpriteKit

         import iAd

     import StoreKit
    var list = [SKProduct]()
    var p = SKProduct()
   class GameScene: SKScene, ADInterstitialAdDelegate, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
   getProductInfo()


      }

  func getProductInfo() {
    if(SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()) {
        print("IAP is enabled, loading")
        var productID:NSSet = NSSet(objects: "remove_ads")
        let request: SKProductsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productID as! Set<String>)
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    } else {
        print("please enable IAPS")
    }



}

func buyProduct() {
    print("buy " + p.productIdentifier)
    var pay = SKPayment(product: p)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(self)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(pay as SKPayment)
}
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedDownloads downloads: [SKDownload]) {

}
   func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, removedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

}
     func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, res    toreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: NSError) {

}
   func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

   }
   func productsRequest (request: SKProductsRequest, didReceiveResponse response: SKProductsResponse) {
    print("product request")
    var myProduct = response.products

    for product in myProduct {
        print("product added")
        print(product.productIdentifier)
        print(product.localizedTitle)
        print(product.localizedDescription)
        print(product.price)

        list.append(product as! SKProduct )
    }
}

func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(queue: SKPaymentQueue!) {
    print("transactions restored")

    var purchasedItemIDS = []
    for transaction in queue.transactions {
        var t: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction

        let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String

        switch prodID {
        case "IAP id here": break


        default:
            print("IAP not setup")
        }

    }

    var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Thank You", message: "Your purchase(s) were restored. You may have to restart the app before banner ads are removed.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    alert.show()
}


func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!) {
    print("add paymnet")

    for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
        var trans = transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction
        print(trans.error)

        switch trans.transactionState {

        case .Purchased, .Restored:
            print("buy, ok unlock iap here")
            //(prprint.productIdentifier)

            let prodID = p.productIdentifier as String
            switch prodID {
            case "IAP id here":


                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Thank You", message: "You may have to restart the app before the banner ads are removed.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()
            default:
                print("IAP not setup")
            }

            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        case .Failed:
            print("buy error")
            queue.finishTransaction(trans)
            break;
        default:
            print("default")
            break;

        }
    }
}

func finishTransaction(trans:SKPaymentTransaction)
{
    print("finish trans")
}
```

Comment: Please clean up your code

Comment: Thanks for noticing! Didn't catch that.

Comment: you should still make sure that your code lines up and formatted correctly

Comment: Okay, so the code is working now(really simple error) and I'm testing on a device, but when I tap the node it won't work, does something need to be called?

Comment: do you have everything set up with Apple, all contracts signed, active profile that is not a wild card, etc

Comment: Yes, everything is ready to go. I have apps released, but this is my first IAP

Comment: wow  you were able to release apps with the way I have seen you code,  Apple must be really getting lax with what gets through.  Anyway, your p variable is global,  but nothing ever gets defined within it, so your productIdentifier must be empty, giving you invalid product ID

Comment: You obviously didn't even read the code. Its used like 4+ times.

Comment: you will need to point it out then because I can't find it

Comment: Wait does the IAP have to go through review before this can work?

Comment: no that would make no sense,  how can you test if your iAP is working before it goes to review if you need to put it through review first

Comment: you need to clean this code that is posted so that it is readable, and you need to point where you do things with p (which should not even be named p, such a bad variable name for a non counter)

Answer (score 2):

The only required function for `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` is

```
paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])
```

Which you have commented out. Just take out those comments and you're set!

Edit: Ah the problem is that you're closing your class without including the rest of your functions!

You can see it here:

```
class GameScene: SKScene, ADInterstitialAdDelegate, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
   getProductInfo()


  }
```

That last curly bracket needs to be cut and pasted to the very end of the file.

Comment: Sorry, that was an error in my writing and I don't know how it got there. Its not like that in my code.

Comment: I have a feeling due to the sloppy nature of the code, that this function is inside another function, so the compiler is not seeing the method as expected

Comment: Yea I don't doubt it. I got a NSInvalidArgumentException, "invalid product ID"

Answer (score 0):

Did you grab the code from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31907050/in-app-purchase-in-skscene)? If not its pretty close to current. Also assuming the error was something along the lines of: Type "YourClass" does not conform to protocol "SKPaymentTransactionObserver".

The problem I think, is that you have:

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue!, updatedTransactions transactions: [AnyObject]!)
```

Try this, I tested it and it got rid of the error:

```
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction])
```

Hope this helps.